# Determining a partition key in Dynamo DB for GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to DynamoDB and I am finding it hard to think of how I should decide my partition key. I am using a condensed version of my use case:

I have an attribute which is a boolean value => B
For a given ID, I need to return all the data for it. The ID is either X or Y attribute. For the given ID, if B is true, I need to read attribute X, else Y.

While inserting into the table I know the the value of B and hence I can fill it in either X or Y depending on the value of it.

However while fetching, I just am given an ID, and I need to figure out whether it exists in column X or column Y ( I won't be getting the value of B in the input).

In a RDBMS I could run a query like `select * from tab where (B == true && X == ID) || (B==false && Y == ID)`.

I think creating a GSI in DynamoDB will be the way to go about solving this in Dynamo. However I am not able to figure out the best way to approach this. Could I get suggestions?

Comment: Asking just in case, do you have any records with both X and Y specified?

Comment: @xtx Yes there might be a case where X & Y are specified. But if B is true only X has to be read from.

Comment: For a given ID, can boolean B take both `true` and `false` values (for different records)?

Comment: @xtx No, an ID will be either true or false

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I got your use case correctly, but why not just swapping target columns based on value B while inserting a row.

Consider the following input:

```
+-----+------+--------+
|  X  |  Y   |   B    |
+-----+------+--------+
| ID1 | ID2  |  true  |
+-----+------+--------+
| ID3 | ID4  |  true  |
+-----+------+--------+
| ID5 | ID6  |  false |
+-----+------+--------+
| ID7 | ID8  |  false |
+-----+------+--------+
```

What if you store the values like this:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
|  id       |      opposite id        |   
|(hash key) | or whatever you call it | 
+-----------+-------------------------+
| ID1       |        ID2              | 
+-----------+-------------------------+
| ID3       |        ID4              | 
+-----------+-------------------------+
| ID6       |        ID5              | 
+-----------+-------------------------+
| ID8       |        ID7              | 
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

This way, while fetching an item by an IDXXX value you would need to perform a query on the single column `id`.

---

**UPD:** Notice, if your use case allows having multiple records with a same id, **you would need an another field to serve as a range key**. This holds true no matter whether you swap columns like shown above or not.

Answer (score -1):

As Per AWS DynamoDB Blog Post : [Choosing the Right DynamoDB Partition Key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)

> **Choosing the Right DynamoDB Partition Key  is an important step in the
>   design  and building of scalable and reliable applications on top of
>   DynamoDB.**
>
> **What is a partition key?**
>
> DynamoDB supports two types of primary keys:
>
> **Partition key**: Also known as a hash key, the partition key is composed of a single attribute. Attributes in DynamoDB are similar in
>   many ways to fields or columns in other database systems.
>
> **Partition key and sort key**: Referred to as a composite primary key or hash-range key, this type of key is composed of two attributes. The
>   first attribute is the partition key, and the second attribute is the
>   sort key. Here is an example:

[image]

> **Why do I need a partition key?**
>
> DynamoDB stores data as groups of attributes, known as items. Items
>   are similar to rows or records in other database systems. DynamoDB
>   stores and retrieves each item based on the primary key value which
>   must be unique. Items are distributed across 10 GB storage units,
>   called partitions (physical storage internal to DynamoDB). Each table
>   has one or more partitions, as shown in Figure 2. For more
>   information, see the Understand Partition Behavior in the DynamoDB
>   Developer Guide.
>
> DynamoDB uses the partition key’s value as an input to an internal
>   hash function. The output from the hash function determines the
>   partition in which the item will be stored. Each item’s location is
>   determined by the hash value of its partition key.
>
> All items with the same partition key are stored together, and for
>   composite partition keys, are ordered by the sort key value. DynamoDB
>   will split partitions by sort key if the collection size grows bigger
>   than 10 GB.

[image]

> **Recommendations for partition keys**
>
> **Use  high-cardinality attributes.** These are attributes that have
>   distinct values for each item  like e-mail id, employee_no,
>   customerid, sessionid, ordered, and so on.
>
> **Use composite attributes.** Try to combine more than one attribute to
>   form a unique key, if that meets your access pattern. For example,
>   consider an orders table with customerid+productid+countrycode as the
>   partition key and order_date as the sort key.
>
> **Cache the popular items** when there is a high volume of read traffic.
>   The cache acts as a low-pass filter, preventing reads of unusually
>   popular items from swamping partitions. For example, consider a table
>   that has deals information for products. Some deals are expected to be
>   more popular than others during major sale events like Black Friday or
>   Cyber Monday.
>
> **Add random numbers/digits from a predetermined range for write-heavy**
>   **use cases.** If you expect a large volume of writes for a partition key,
>   use an additional prefix or suffix (a fixed number from predeternmined
>   range, say 1-10) and add it to the partition key.  For example, 
>   consider a table of invoice transactions. A single invoice can contain
>   thousands of transactions per client.

Read More @ [Choosing the Right DynamoDB Partition Key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)